# Powershell 2.0 - Conditional (Else) not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to produce a powershell script that contains an (IF, Else) statement. Mainly due to compatibility issues in how the different versions call web requests.

```
V < 2.0 : Uses [System.Net.WebRequest] for HTTP Requests
```

&

```
V > 2.0 : Uses Invoke-WebRequest
```

Here is my code :

```
$pcName="$ENV:COMPUTERNAME";
$psVers=$host.Version.Major;

if ($psVers -le 2) 

            {$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://xxx.co.kr'); 
             $request.Method = "POST"; $request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
             $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("pcName=$pcName"); 
             $request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length; $requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream(); 
             $requestStream.Write( $bytes, 0, $bytes.Length ); $requestStream.Close(); 
             $request.GetResponse();}

Else  
            {$POSTdata = @{pcName=$pcName} 
             Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://xxx.co.kr -Method POST -Body $POSTdata};
```

And here is the error that I am receiving from Powershell v-2.0 :

```
The term 'Else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ Else <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty line above the Else keyword:

```
$pcName="$ENV:COMPUTERNAME";
$psVers=$host.Version.Major;

if ($psVers -le 2) 

            {$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://xxx.co.kr'); 
             $request.Method = "POST"; $request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
             $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("pcName=$pcName"); 
             $request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length; $requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream(); 
             $requestStream.Write( $bytes, 0, $bytes.Length ); $requestStream.Close(); 
             $request.GetResponse();}
Else  
            {$POSTdata = @{pcName=$pcName} 
             Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://xxx.co.kr -Method POST -Body $POSTdata};
```